# Differential equations with a derivative in the exponent

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to know if there is a method to find solutions to ODEs where the derivative is in the exponent.

For example:

$y^{y'}=y''$

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: My first idea would be to apply the natural log to both sides and see what happens. This way you can eliminate exponents (though you might be stuck with logarithms instead, so who knows if this works).

Comment: Your eqn can be transformed to the form $z’+z\log(z)=\varphi(\xi)$. Seems more reasonable but I haven’t been able to find anything on it.

Comment: There really is nothing you can do this type of equation, other than numerically solving it, or brute-force.